Deform a volume ray
I'm very new to blender so sorry in advance if my question is easy to answer.
I want to create a god ray effect and followed a youtube video using a Voronoi texture.
Here is the result:

The results looks good, but now I want to make it as if the ray is coming from a window and lighting the room in a cone shape. I tried to edit the shape of the volume cube in edit mode but the shape of the ray is not deformed.

This is what I would like to do:

What should I do to deform the ray?
Many thanks in advance for your kind help!

You're using Generated coordinates, which is just gonna be like Object space coords. They stay static, and won't deform with the mesh. Ideally you would use UV coords so you could distort the mesh and they would follow, but those don't work with Volumetric stuff. You could just do what we do in games, turn the cone inside out, scale the UVs all the way down on the vertical axis and then use that texture as an emissive and alpha input. You don't always need actual volumetrics, just the appearance of volumetrics.

I see. Thanks for the explanation, much appreciate it! Will do as you described, many thanks for your kind help.

Sure thing, lmk if you have any other questions about this method.

Fake ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZI2pqcp8ig

You can use

Light type Point or Spot
some holed mesh to block light rays
and some volumetric volume ...

Here is used subdiv plane with random select and deleted faces as light stopper.

Notes:

Light set Radius to zero for sharper god rays
In this example Color Management is set with Exposure 3 and Gamma 0.3.




